# Run hive-mq broker as what user?

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, hivemq

I am trying to run the Hive-MQ broker (version 1.4.2) on my ubuntu machine.

When I am trying to connect with my MQTT-client which is running on a telematics unit, I get loads of errors, this being one of them:

```
2013-11-18 11:20:25,510 ERROR - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging 
expired org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /home/ubuntu/hivemq
/data/cache/clientSessions is not directory or IO error occurred when listing 
files with filterorg.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@4d9c113e 
[fileExists=false, isDirector=false, canRead=false, canWrite=false]
at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459)
at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218)
```

All the errors complain about directories not existing. I get the same result when i run `./run.sh` as well as `sudo ./run.sh`.

Anyone else had this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it seems there is something wrong with the directory permissions. 
Did you use the official getting started instructions? http://www.hivemq.com/documentations/getting-started/

In general it should be enough to unzip the file, go into the folder and start HiveMQ with: ./bin/run.sh

You can also try to remove everything from within the data/cache directory.

Best regards,

Chris

Comment: That's exactly what we've done. One weird this is that, as soon as one of our clients connect, the ownership of the entire hivemq directory is changed from `ubuntu:ubuntu` to `ubuntu:root`. Also, the files and folders in `/hive-mq/data/cache` are removed. It does seem like the problem is for the HiveMQ server to create new files, but we can't figure out why?

Comment: Is this problem still there?

Comment: No it is not. It was the init.d script provided that did not work very well with an Ubuntu AMI from Amazon. I changed to a upstart-job instead which I know more about :)

Comment: ok great. yes, I know the init.d script was not ideal for debian based systems, so in the HiveMQ 1.5.0 release we included an extra script for these systems.